# adding contents to DOM elements from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `contents` object and inside that I have some data. What I am doing it I am first grabbing class name of a div tag and then based on that class name I want to grab data from contents based on this class. Here is my code

```
var contents = {
    inner_one: {
        title: 'This is title for one',
        body: 'This is body for one'
    },
    inner_two: {
        title: 'This is title for two',
        body: 'This is body for two'
    }
};

var inner = $(div).attr('class'); //here lets say inner = inner_one

console.log(contents.inner);
```

But my above code does not work. I assume because my code looks for `inner` object inside `contents` which does not exist. Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a *dynamic object property access*, we need to use the *bracket notation*.

```
console.log( contents[ inner ] );
```

Hence, we can't dynamically access property names using the *dot notation*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexer `[]` and pass the `variable` that contain attribute name to get the value of `property`.

*Change*

```
console.log(contents.inner);
```

*To*

```
console.log(contents[inner]);
```

Comment: Why this is working if you could explain it bit, much useful to everyone here.

Comment: I told to use indexer, it is they way to access property of object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your JSON string first,

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(contents);
```

then try console.log

```
console.log(obj[inner]);
```

But validate your json string first.

Comment: contents is not a JSON string, it's a plain object